Baxter arm can't reach goal pose parallel to the ground while simulating in gazebo ignition fortress
I'm having problems with simulating Baxter arms in the gazebo ignition fortress. First problem that arised is that, when spawning in ignition, his arms are oscillating for a long time. I managed to mitigate that problem by increasing the damping property in the dynamics tag of every joint.
The main problem that is still unsolved, is that when I give baxter goal pose with which his arm would be almost straight and parallel to the ground, it either: won't arrive to that pose, it will go to that pose really slowly, it will kinda reach that pose but then arm will just fall down. Example of the problem can be seen in the video.
But for every trajectory move_group node outputs Completed trajectory execution with status SUCCEEDED even if it didn't arrive to the goal pose.
That problem isn't happening with other poses. Also none of this happens only using rviz, so I guess the problem is somewhere with ros2 controllers and urdf/gazebo.
For the setup, I am using gazebo ignition fortress with moveit2, for controlling the arms I am using ros2_control. I coppied the official urdf from the RethinkRobotics github, changed dampings and some joint names because some joints had the same name as the links and gazebo was complaining, added necesessary ros2_control and gazebo elements.
Here is my baxter2_include.urdf.xacro which includes other necessary urdfs: baxter2.urdf.xacro, my_gazebo.urdf.xacro, my_baxter_arm.ros2_control.xacro, my_baxter_hand.ros2_control.xacro.
Here are other needed yaml files: ros2_controllers.yaml, yaml file needed for moveit controllers.
Any help is appreciated!

It seems like the mass and inertial elemets of the arm are too great for the set effort of the joints. Basically the arm is too heavy for the described joint actuators.
Gazebo or other simulators use the mass and inertial elements from URDFs like this. RViz does not, which is why it has no issues like this. The MockController (which is usually used for visualizing arm movement) does not actually simulate the arm's physics.
Increasing the effort of each joint, decreasing the mass of each link and/or re-balancing the inertial properties should help solve this problem.

increasing the effort solved the problem, it also solved the problem of oscillating arms so now I don't even need dynamics tag. Thank you very much for your help!!
